# Error when deploying Flask + Vue app to heroku

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, heroku, npm

I am trying to deploy my flask/vue app to heroku but I am having difficulties.
I have mainly followed these instructions (https://medium.com/the-andela-way/deploying-a-python-flask-app-to-heroku-41250bda27d0) and I tried following this [Heroku deployment confusion: Vue.js frontend with Flask backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134246/heroku-deployment-confusion-vue-js-frontend-with-flask-backend) but I fell short.

**Procedure I followed**

I started in the root directory  My_app_folder of my test.py file and activated a virtual environment "my-venv"
Then:

1. logged in to heroku
2. installed gunicorn
3. ran pip freeze > requirements.txt
4. Created procfile;   web: npm install; npm run dev; gunicorn test:app
5. Created app "garemo1" using: "heroku create garemo1-api-heroku"
6. ran: git add .
7. ran: git commit -m "committed"
8. ran: git push heroku master

I also created and ran the following buildpacks:

```
 heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

Then added the following line in "scripts" in package.json:

```
"heroku-prebuild": "npm install",
"heroku-postbuild": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js"
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-proj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.6.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "require-vuejs": "^1.1.3",
    "v-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-range-component": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-range-slider": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-simple-alert": "^1.1.1",
    "vuex": "^3.3.0",
    "vuex-persist": "^2.2.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": false,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

In my test.py script I have:

```
 app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = "static", template_folder = "Templates/vue_template")
```

This is the structure of my app

```
My_app_folder
|   package.json
|   Procfile
|   requirements.txt
|   test.py
+---frontend
|   \---sample-proj
|       |   .gitignore
|       |   babel.config.js
|       |   package-lock.json
|       |   package.json
|       |   README.md
|       |   vue.config.js
|       \---public
|       |   favicon.ico
|       |   index.html

|       \---node_modules

|       \---src
|       |   App.vue
|       |   main.js
|       |   router.js          
|       |   \---assets
|       |   |    logo.png
|       |   \---components
|       |   |   AddProduct.vue
|       |   |   category.vue
|       |   |   HelloWorld.vue
|       |   |   susScore.vue
|       |   \---Views
|       |   |   AddProductView.vue
|       |   |   createlist.vue
|       |   |   grocerylist.vue
|       |   |   loginpage.vue
+---static
|       \---css
|       \---img
|       \---js
+---Templates
|       \---vue_template
|       |   \---favicon.ico
|       |   \---index.html
```

I have package.json in two places because I got the following error message and placing package.json  near test.py solved the error:

```
The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of the directory structure.")
```

These are the error messages I get from running "heroku logs --tail" after following the above procedure.

```
26T15:28:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2020-06-26T15:30:45.878824+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9c824365 by user 
2020-06-26T15:30:45.878824+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user 
2020-06-26T15:30:46.655593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-06-26T15:30:59.195699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm install; npm run dev; gunicorn test:app`
2020-06-26T15:31:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-26T15:31:08.495145+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2020-06-26T15:31:08.495623+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-26T15:31:08.707457+00:00 app[web.1]: audited 1421 packages in 7.272s
2020-06-26T15:31:09.938506+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-26T15:31:09.938521+00:00 app[web.1]: 3 packages are looking for funding
2020-06-26T15:31:09.938522+00:00 app[web.1]: run `npm fund` for details
2020-06-26T15:31:09.938522+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-26T15:31:09.939188+00:00 app[web.1]: found 0 vulnerabilities
2020-06-26T15:31:09.939189+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-26T15:31:11.091549+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: dev
2020-06-26T15:31:11.151505+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-26T15:31:11.151820+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-26T15:31:11.151997+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-26T15_31_11_092Z-debug.log
2020-06-26T15:31:11.450019+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-26 15:31:11 +0000] [34] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-06-26T15:31:11.450577+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-26 15:31:11 +0000] [34] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:19276 (34)
2020-06-26T15:31:11.450696+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-26 15:31:11 +0000] [34] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-06-26T15:31:11.454931+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-26 15:31:11 +0000] [37] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 37
2020-06-26T15:31:11.983153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-26T15:32:38.550577+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.29.86.227 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:32:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1065 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-26T15:32:38.557399+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=0f61456b-6fb1-47d9-9e5d-190c94ba4a80 fwd="94.137.125.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=1227 protocol=https
2020-06-26T15:32:38.692120+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.29.86.227 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:32:38 +0000] "GET /static/css/app.37905c57.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-26T15:32:38.694490+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.33.250.117 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:32:38 +0000] "GET /static/css/chunk-vendors.32e65282.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-26T15:32:38.698935+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/app.37905c57.css" host=garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=c8f8e2ee-75c5-4d15-910b-256b65f83d13 fwd="94.137.125.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2020-06-26T15:32:38.709886+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/chunk-vendors.32e65282.css" host=garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=b8657054-8e04-44bf-a3c2-e2e8af7ee15e fwd="94.137.125.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2020-06-26T15:32:38.807810+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.29.86.227 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:32:38 +0000] "GET /static/js/app.765edbcb.js HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-26T15:32:38.811269+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.33.250.117 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:32:38 +0000] "GET /static/js/chunk-vendors.b338db17.js HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-26T15:32:38.814797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/app.765edbcb.js" host=garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=da71bbcc-d4fa-462a-b1de-b2064b58170d fwd="94.137.125.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2020-06-26T15:32:38.820860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/chunk-vendors.b338db17.js" host=garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=d3a3b311-fe1c-4b8b-bc28-44fc0964de4a fwd="94.137.125.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2020-06-26T15:32:38.931285+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.33.250.117 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:32:38 +0000] "GET /static/js/app.765edbcb.js HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-26T15:32:38.940610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/app.765edbcb.js" host=garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=8c425e66-b016-4ba3-b310-77adafda192d fwd="94.137.125.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2020-06-26T15:44:34.354407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/app.37905c57.css" host=garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=e990d878-4e51-4820-850b-63fb04c16441 fwd="94.137.125.198" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2020-06-26T15:44:34.345656+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.192.219 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:44:34 +0000] "GET /static/css/app.37905c57.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-26T16:21:19.035914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-06-26T16:21:19.039332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-06-26T16:21:20.166771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-26T16:21:20.196557+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-26 16:21:20 +0000] [34] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-06-26T16:21:20.255333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

This is part of the error I get in the console after trying to deploy using the procedure above

```
https://garemo1-api-heroku.herokuapp.com/static/css/app.37905c57.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

**Question**
How can I solve the errors so that I can deploy my app?

Comment: I think `npm ERR! missing script: dev` is triggered by `npm run dev` in the Procfile.  Possibly change that to use something from the "scripts" object in your package.json, eg `npm run serve`.

Comment: Thanks,I tried changin npm run dev to npm run serve (and npm run build) in the Procfile but neither worked. Should I try to add something to the package,json file aswell?